# How should I stay in touch with the professor with whom I have arranged an internship?

Tags: research-undergraduate, email, international-students, internship

This professor has accepted me for an undergrad research internship in 2017. How should I stay in touch and continue our email conversations for the following months? I did ask her to send me some papers of hers and I read them. Now what should I do to continue to look interested in her research?

Comment: If you've already been accepted for the internship, and you (hopefully) intend to work hard and be enthusiastic during the internship, then why do you feel that you need to maintain an appearance of interest in the meantime?

Comment: It's a very prestigious International Internship. I thought it will be good to stay in touch till the internship starts. It's my first time to get selected for an International internship and I want to make the most of it.

Comment: Well, you don't really want to start the internship *now*, on a remote basis.  So just send an email once every three months or so with some news about yourself and your studies.

Comment: Would @aparente001 move their comment to become an answer so that the question would be marked as answered?

Comment: @G-E - Okay, I did, but don't hold your breath, it's been a year and a half....

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't really want to start the internship *now*, on a remote basis. So just send an email once every three months or so with some news about yourself and your studies.

If you want to write a bit more often, that's okay too.  I wouldn't write more than once a month, though.

Comment: I wouldn't write at all until about 2 to 4 weeks before the internship (to remind them that you'll start soon), except if there is a need to discuss administrative stuff. Most professors have more important things to do than keeping up-to-date on the life of an undergrad.

Comment: @Roland - You're welcome to write an answer.  I don't want to edit my answer to follow the ideas in your comment, because I think that as long as the newsy email doesn't request assistance or information, it will take up minimal time on the prof's part.